# does the rule : 'kth iteration relaxes all nodes that are atmost k edges from source' work for all graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

in the Bellman-ford algo, we know that, at kth iteration, nodes that are at atmost k edges from the source, obtain their best value. but does this rule apply to all possible graphs (all directed)?

see the graph below, doesn't this graph break the above-mentioned rule? if not? then how would it still hold?

[image: reference graph]

Comment: There is no such thing, as this graph shows too. I think there is some confusion and it could come from two things:

1) Instead of _k_, if you put _N_, iterating _N-1_ times all nodes set their best value, as any node is at most _N-1_ edges from the source. This isn't true for any other _k_ though.

2) Wiki: "For every _i_, after the _i_ th iteration, from any vertex _v_... yields a path that has a total weight that is at most _distance[v]_, ... lower bound for any path that **uses at most _i_ edges**." This is the "best value" from max _i_ length paths, but there could be longer paths!